# Outlook Issue with running BAT file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, batch-file, shared-folders

Recently I have been having an issue with sending a hyperlink to a `.BAT` file saved on our shared drive. When the person receiving the email clicks the link and try to run the `.BAT` file, they get an error message stating:

> Something unexpected went wrong with this URL file:///\(shared drive - folder - `.BAT` file)

Would anyone happen to know as to why this is happening and is there a way to avoid this issue from preventing the person to click the hyperlink and run the `.BAT` file from the shared drive?

Comment: You could probably include some more info: 1 - Did this same link work before and then stopped? 2 - The full URL (sanitized if necessary).

Additional basic troubleshooting: Have you verified the user can access the batch file in the first place? Did you check eventviewer on the client station? Logged events often have more details.

Also, your file->UNC url above only has one backslash...

Comment: It appears to be an anti-virus update that went through not to long ago. We are all able to access the shared drive as I send excel files with link to open the report without an issue. But since it seems to look like it is some type of install file, the anti-virus program is blocking outlook from running the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself a while back. I think it was the anti-virus software interfering. The solution was to zip the file and mail it, ...have the user unzip it and it will work.

Comment: After some digging around, it is a anti-virus update that recently went through. Since it thinks the file is some type of install file, it is blocking the person from running the install.